# Setting up SQL server 2012 failover clustering in local environment

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster

this is my first time trying to set up a failover clustering for sql server and would like to understand a few concept and see if its legitimate to do.

I am currently trying to set up this failover cluster for test purposes in a local network environment. where I have a PC with existing sql server 2012 db server hosted with data inside, I am thinking of setting up another sql server 2012 db on another pc in same local network as the second node 2 to this cluster, would that work?

When I try to use the sql server 2012 installer, under installation option, however, I do not see "new SQL server failover cluster installation". Do I have to run it on a PC without sql server installed already to get that option? Or do I have to run the enterprise version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set up the failover cluster first. Next go to the node 1 server in your cluster and install SQL Server as the first install in the cluster. Then go to the node 2 to install SQL Server. It will know this is install number 2 in the cluster. Repeat for how ever many nodes are in the cluster. This assumes you are setting up active-passive cluster.

If you can, work with someone who understands how to set up the cluster environment and how to install software to work within the cluster configuration.

More details here: http://www.handsonsqlserver.com/how-to-install-sql-server-on-an-activepassive-cluster/

Comment: Could you tell me what version of SQL server I would need? I assume the express version won't do.                                             And also, do I have to purchase the MSCS environment? Or can all these be setup free? Thanks